# Exception handling internal bug

Tags: c#, asp.net

Code:

```
public static void Test()
{
   try
   {
       OpenConnectionToDatabase(); //Opens a connection to Oracle DB

   } catch(Exception e)
   {
       e.Data.Add("Query:", command.CommandText);
       throw e;
   }
}
```

When this code is executed when the Database server is being shutdown and the communication is disrupted, .NET throws the following error:
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Query:' Key being added: 'Query:'
at  System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.Add(Object key, Object value)

How can this be?

Comment: What does OpenConnectionToDatabase actually do?

Comment: `OpenConnectionToDatabase()` has the exact same exception handling?

Comment: Maybe the Data dictionary in the exception already has an entry for that key.

Comment: OpenConnectionToDatabase just opens a connection to the database which fails when DB is being shutdown. OpenConnectionToDatabase does throw it's own exception BUT IT DOES NOT add anything to the Data property.

Comment: The Data dictionary in that exception has ZERO entries. It is only populated in the catch block of the Test() method. It's like the code  e.Data.Add("Query:", command.CommandText); executes twice in the catch block.

Comment: @user666423:  Stepping through the code should confirm the two executions...

Comment: FYI, `throw e` will cause the stack trace of the exception to be reset.  Use plain `throw` instead.  See http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000352.html

Comment: This error only happens rarely and seems to be caused when the DB server is in the process of shutting down, it seems to be a bug internally.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: (based on @LukeH's comment)

```
e.Data["Query:"] = command.CommandText;
```

Comment: I don't know about this... What if the existing value of "Query:" is different?  You'll lose valuable debugging info.

Comment: +1 for Austin's comment, but if you *did* want to just overwrite the existing "Query:" item then you don't need the `Contains` check, since using the indexer will add or overwrite as necessary: `e.Data["Query:"] = command.CommandText;` will do the trick.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the issue happens. There shouldn't be ANYTHING in e.Data after OpenConnectionToDatabase throws an exception. It's only in the catch block where e.Data is populated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "`throw e;`". Just use `throw`.

Comment: Definitely good advice, but not really an answer to the question. Should probably be a comment.